# What are the valid characters that can be used for AWS S3 User name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to know about the valid character list that can be used for the User name in AWS S3.

Comment: s3 bucket name? which user name ?

Comment: The name of the User that has the access to the Bucket.

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of an "Amazon S3 user". Users can be defined in IAM and they can be granted permission to access Amazon S3 buckets.

When creating an IAM User in the management console, a message appears if invalid symbols are entered:

> User names can contain alphanumeric characters, or any of the following: `_+=,.@-`

Also, from [Creating an IAM User in Your AWS Account - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html#id_users_create_console):

> User names can be a combination of up to 64 letters, digits, and these characters: plus (`+`), equal (`=`), comma (`,`), period (`.`), at sign (`@`), underscore (`_`), and hyphen (`-`).

Comment: can you share the link where I can find this information about IAM Users and naming conventions. Thanks

Comment: Link added to answer